# Objects are not valid as a React child : Error while using setState

Tags: reactjs

I am getting the above mentioned error.I have gone through the related thread links but not solving my issue.I understood that this issue come when I am trying to set the state with an **object** rather than using **array**.

I have one siteProductTestContainer.js

```js
import React from "react";
import api from "../networking/api";
import ProductList from "./components/ProductList";

class siteProductTestContainer extends React.Component {
    state = {
      products: []
    };

    componentDidMount = () => {
      //make an api call to get the data
      const dataToSend = {
        customerNumber: this.props.propsAppData["customerNumber"],
        elid: this.props.propsAppData["elid"]
      };

      const callback = responseData => {
        console.log("DataType of products-->", typeof this.state.products); //object
        console.log("DataType of responseData", typeof responseData); //object
        console.log("DataType of responseData.services-->", typeof responseData.services);
//object

        this.setState({
          products: responseData.services
        });
        console.log("After updating state");
        console.log("Current state is ", this.state);

        api.siteProduct(dataToSend, callback);
      };

      render() {
        return ( <
          div >
          <
          ProductList productList = {
            this.state.products
          }
          name = "pourush" / >
          <
          /div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default siteProductTestContainer;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.2.0/react.min.js"></script>
```

So,Suppose I am getting the data in responseData as :

```
{
  "site-services": {
    "cNum": "the customer number to whom the service belong to",
    "eId": "the site elid whose services are requested",
    "services": [
      {
        "name": "service 1",
        "serviceId": "123456"
      },
      {
        "name": "service 2",
        "serviceId": "147852"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Question : In responseData,I am already getting services as **an array of objects**,but still I am not being able to map using setstate() ?

Comment: most likely you render Object in `ProductList ` component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually,these type of error Occurs where your components are nested and you are trying to pass down the the data from parent component to the child one.

The Error gets bubbled up and shown at the top component, but actually the error occurs at the Inner child.

And Somewhere in Inner child component, we need to loop in Array of objects to extract the data and render it correctly.

I debugged from parent to child and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

`services` in not directly available under `responseData`, you need to get it from `"site-services"` like

```
   this.setState({
      products: responseData["site-services"].services
    });
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for writing in.
If I print responseData , It looks like this :

  "cNum": "the customer number to whom the service belong to",
    "eId": "the site elid whose services are requested",
    "services": [
      {
        "name": "service 1",
        "serviceId": "123456"
      },
      {
        "name": "service 2",
        "serviceId": "147852"
      }
    ]

Comment: **So , responseData.services is accessible !! **